# Algebra, subspace,linear independence of vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra

**In $R^{3}$ are given 3 vectors** $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$ $\begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ $\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix}$. **Find dimension and base of subspace generated by these vectors.**

$\alpha \cdot\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$ $+\beta\cdot\begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ $+\gamma\cdot\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ we receive : $\alpha=\beta=\gamma$ so they aren't linearly independent?

But each two of vectors are linearly independent, so dimension of base: dim=$R^{2}$ , and base of subspace is for example 
$\left\{ \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\-1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix} \right\}$ because these two are linearly independent. Is it correct? Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: Essentially yes, you are at it. The three vectors are dependent, so you can take your choice of two vectors as indicated and use those for your sub space

Comment: Thank you for taking the time also to typeset your question in MathJax.  It really does help make it easier to read.  As a small suggestion for future reference, you can use `\left` and `\right` on braces to make them large enough to fit around what they contain.  `\left\{\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\-1\end{bmatrix},\dots\right\}` produces $\left\{\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\-1\end{bmatrix},\dots\right\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you're right. A set of vectors forms a base only if they are linearly independent, that means that no other solution exists than the trivial solution for the linear combination, which is:

$\alpha=0; \beta=0; \gamma=0$ which you have proven not to be satisfied.

Also, the dimension of a space is given by the cardinality of the base, the number of vectors of the set. In your case, $\dim_{R}R^{2}=2$ since the base you've chosen for the subspace has two vectors.

Comment: @kubox what exactly means  $\dim_{R}R^{2}$ = 2   this small $_{R}$ especially. I think only about way of writing it mathematicaly correctly.

Comment: @NowakGrzegorz I've written that way since you haven't specified the dimension of a vector space over a field. I found the following link useful, btw you should read the "Facts" section too (might be helpful for you) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_(vector_space)#Examples